# Angular + Bootstrap style theme

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm using Angular 5 + Bootstrap 4, and I'm trying to make a style theme.
I made something quite simple yet but it still doesn't work (doesn't compile).

src/style.scss :

```
@function theme($key: "primary") {
  @return map-get($theme-colors, $key);
}

$theme-colors: (
  "bg": #888,
  "bg-title": #555,
  "danger": #ff4136
);

* {
  background: theme("bg");
}
```

src/app/header/header.component.scss :

```
* {
  background: $theme("bg-title");
}
```

ERROR :

```
ERROR in ./src/app/header/header.component.scss
Module build failed:
  background: $theme("bg-title");
             ^
      Undefined variable: "$theme".
      in C:\Users\crelierj\projects\ba\bootang\src\app\header\header.component.scss (line 2, column 15)

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

I understand the problem, what I defined in style.scss isn't recognized in header.component.scss.
But I don't know how could I do this ? I'd like to define some global functions and theme I could use in any components, and I tought style.scss was the way to do it.

Could someone tell me how to do it properly please ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the `style.scss` in your `header.component.scss` first:

```
  @import './src/style.scss';
  ...
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, thanks, I had to remove $ in my scss and it was styles.scss but otherwise it's what I needed. Is there a way to automatically include it everywhere ? Or I'll have to import everytime.

Comment: [Yeah, I guess](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli#toc-sass-include-paths), but I have not tried it yet.